# Trouble using pip to install httplib

Tags: python, pip, httplib

I recently deleted and reinstalled Pip, and I have been having problems using pip ever since then. I'm trying to install a module called httplib however my Mac terminal comes up with the following error:

```
JohnDoe@138-38-164-231 ~ % python3 -m pip install httplib
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ornado (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ertifi (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ornado (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ertifi (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement httplib (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for httplib
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ornado (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ertifi (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ornado (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ertifi (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ornado (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ertifi (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages)
WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.
```

If anybody knows what this error means or how to fix it I would appreciate the help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**httplib** is a standard library module in Python, so it is already included in ***Python 3.7***. You do not need to install it using pip. But httplib module has been renamed to http.client in Python3.

You can directly import it into your code using the following statement:

```
import http.client as httplib
```